# iOS provisioning profile

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

Usually I can always find what I'm looking for on Stack Overflow.  But this time I'm really stumped.

I've read other Stack Overflow responses for people who have had a similar problem to this; but to no avail.  (I think some of that is that I'm using Mavericks and I recently updated Xcode to 6.0.1.)

My woes began with getting this warning from Xcode:  “Target Integrity  Provisioning profile is expiring...” which was true.  I had recently renewed my developer's license and I did need to update the provisioning profile.

So before I updated Xcode, I went to the iOS dev center and created a new provisioning profile and downloaded it.  I selected it in Window->Organizer / Devices and I removed the old one.  But the warning did not go away.

I read a post on Stack Overflow, from someone who could not delete their provisioning profile.  They suggested using the iPhone Configuration Utility.  I went to that web link for that program; and read there that for Mavericks, I should now use the Apple Configurator.

I downloaded the Apple Configurator but when I began using the program, I couldn't readily see anything about provisioning profiles.

I began to think, maybe I did need the older program called iPhone Configuration Utility after all.  So I downloaded that, and it installed.  But I cannot find it anywhere.  I'm so confused by that.  Is the iPhone Configuration Utility part of Xcode or part of Apple Configurator now?

To make matters so much worse, after I updated to Xcode 6.0.1, the screen in Windows->Organizer / Devices where I was able to see my provisioning profiles and add and remove them is gone!  (I'm not sure where it got moved or how to get to it.)

I'm worried if I don't take care of this warning soon the app may stop working because it's referencing the expired provisioning profile.

Has anyone had some success updating a provisioning profile with Mavericks and Xcode 6.0.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well all you need is access to your developer portal and Xcode.

If your provisioning profile is expiring soon, all you need to do is to go to your developer portal > provisioning profiles > click on the one expiring > renew or regenerate.

After you do that, go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Your Account > View Details > Refresh and you should be good to go.

It won't hurt to clean up your project after this procedure.

Edit:
Also check if your selected provisioning profiles for your project's schemas are valid and the ones you actually need.
[image]

As for your expiring provisioning profile, that's the one managed by Xcode. You can delete it from your developer portal without any worries and go to Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > Your Account > View Details > Refresh for Xcode to create a new general development provisioning profile for you automatically.

[image]

Comment: And it was just that simple!  I had already done the provisioning profile part, so I just did the Xcode part you described.  That was it!  It works!  Thank you, thank you!  I've been frustrated for days!  :)

Comment: Sorry, Almost that simple.  I had already done the provisioning profile part, so I just did the Xcode part you described.  
I did the clean and the warnings went away.  
All looked good until I tried to run it on my iPad and then I got a Warning and an error:
Dependency Analysis Warning  The provisioning profile “iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *” is expiring soon.
CodeSign error:  no provisioning profile at path '/Users/.../LibraryMobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/......mobileprovision'

Comment: Go to your project's target build settings > code signing > check if your provisioning profiles match your build schemas and that they are valid. @user3807861 check my edit.

Comment: Ok, it finally builds again.  I went to the screen in the picture you posted.  
I did a clean and all went good.  
Then I just did a build and it failed; but this time a pop up appeared in Xcode asking if I wanted Xcode to resolve the issue.  
I approved and then Xcode did some downloading from my account and then the project built with no warnings and no errors!  I was able to successfully run my code on my iPad again!  Thanks again so much for all that help!

Comment: I'd up vote the answer, but I don't have enough reputation.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when I refreshed my xcode account's provisioning profiles, the provisioning profiles just got replaced with some ID that looks like this`as2d-12asdsd-13asd-ad3as-8sds`, solution is to just choose the correct provisioning profile again, if the provisioning profiles are updated, the updated profile should be there.

***THIS IS IMPORTANT, MAKE SURE THAT BOTH THE PROJECT AND THE TARGET PROVISIONING PROFILES WERE CHANGED***